# Unwanted CSS added to abstracted HTML file

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several web development projects hosted online. I decided it was important to get the projects into source control, so I created copies of the files on my local machine. The way the projects are hosted online, the css and js are inserted by the website and they don't need to be added to the html code. To develop on my machine, I require the js and css files to be added directly to the html, but I don't want to add anything unnecessary to the code that will be placed back online. My solution is an abstracted html file called main. The css and js are added to the main.html file and the original html file is linked in. Like so...

```
 <!-- main.html-->
 <head>
  <script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
   </head>


 <link rel="stylesheet"href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

This works great if the head section is added to the original html file. If the head section is removed, there is unwanted css that suddenly afflicts the original html file.

```
      <!--original.html-->
       <head>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
   </head>

   <body> ... </body>
```

works fine, but contains the code that I want to abstract.

```
     <!--original.html-->
     <body>...</body>
```

has messed up margins from unwanted CSS

in the main.html file, the original html is linked from a git hub page with

```
    <div w3-include-html="github.com/original.html"></div>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this happen only in **`Google Chrome`**?

Comment: No, this also happens with Internet Explorer and Edge.